1st and 2nd uniqueness theorems for primary decomposition of modules
In Chapter 4 of Atiyah, Macdonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra, we find the following exercises:

4.21. An element $x \in A$ defines an endomorphism $\phi_x$ of $M$, namely $m \mapsto x m$. The element $x$ is said to be a zero-divisor (resp. nilpotent) in $M$ if $\phi_x$ is not injective
(resp. is nilpotent). A submodule $Q$ of $M$ is primary in $M$ if $Q \neq M$ and every zero-divisor in $M / Q$ is nilpotent.
Show that if $Q$ is primary in $M$, then $(Q: M)$ is a primary ideal and hence $r_M(Q)$ is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. We say that $Q$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary (in $M$).
Prove the analogues of (4.3) and (4.4).
4.22. A primary decomposition of $N$ in $M$ is a representation of $N$ as an intersection
$$
N=Q_1 \cap \cdots \cap Q_n
$$
of primary submodules of $M$; it is a minimal primary decomposition if the ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i=r_M\left(Q_i\right)$ are all distinct and if none of the components $Q_i$ can be omitted from the intersection, that is if $Q_i \nsupseteq \bigcap_{j \neq i} Q_j\;(1 \leqslant i \leqslant n)$.
Prove the analogue of (4.5), that the prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$ depend only on $N$ (and $M$ ). They are called the prime ideals belonging to $N$ in $M$. Show that they are also the prime ideals belonging to 0 in $M / N$.
4.23. State and prove the analogues of (4.6)-(4.11) inclusive. (There is no loss of generality in taking $N=0$.)

I am trying to work out exercises 4.22 and 4.23. How does one proceed?

$\def\p{\mathfrak{p}}
\def\q{\mathfrak{q}}$Byeongsu Yu has uploaded the solution to their solution manual (saved for posterity in the Wayback Machine). Here are some improvements on the generalized statements:
Proposition 4.6⁎ has a typo in its statement: at the end it should be “containing $r_M(N)$” (not $N$).
At the end of Proposition 4.7⁎'s statement I would rather write “belonging to the zero submodule of $M$,” for precision.
The following is an enhancement of Yu's version:

Proposition 4.8⁎. Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$ and let $\p\subset A$ be a prime. Let $M$ be an $A$-module and let $Q\subset M$ be a submodule.

If $S\cap\p\neq\varnothing$ and $Q$ is a $\p$-primary submodule of $M$, then $S^{-1}Q=S^{-1}M$.
If $S\cap\p=\varnothing$, then $Q$ is a $\p$-primary submodule of $M$ if and only if $S^{-1}Q$ is an $S^{-1}\p$-primary submodule of $S^{-1}M$ and $Q^{ec}=Q$.

Hence, if $\p\cap S=\varnothing$, then $\p$-primary submodules of $M$ that are contractions of submodules of $S^{-1}M$ correspond exactly to $S^{-1}\p$-primary submodules of $S^{-1}M$.

By $(-)^e$ and $(-)^c$ we mean respectively the maps $N\subset M\mapsto S^{-1}N$ and $N'\subset S^{-1}M\mapsto N'\cap M$ between $A$-submodules of $M$ and $S^{-1}A$-submodules of $S^{-1}M$. Condition $Q^{ec}=Q$ means precisely that $Q$ is a contracted submodule by the following

Lemma 1.17⁎. Let $F:X\rightleftarrows Y:G$ be a Galois connection between posets $X$ and $Y$, i.e., $F$ and $G$ are monotone and $x\leq FGx,\;GFy\leq y$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$. Then:

$G=GFG$, $F=FGF$,
If $C=\operatorname{Im}G$, $E=\operatorname{Im}F$, then $C=\{x\in X\mid GFx=x\}$, $E=\{y\in Y\mid FGy=y\}$ and $F:C\rightleftarrows E:G$ are mutually inverse poset isomorphisms.


The lemma is a generalization of (1.17) and is left as an exercise.
Proof of Proposition 4.8⁎. Part 1 is proven by Yu. We see part 2; suppose $S\cap\p=\varnothing$. Yu showed that if $Q\subset M$ is $\p$-primary then $S^{-1}Q\subset S^{-1}M$ is $S^{-1}\p$-primary. It is left to see that $Q=Q^{ce}$. In general $(\subset)$ always holds. To see $(\supset)$, we use the fact that $N^{ce}=\bigcup_{s\in S}(N:s)$ for any submodule $N\subset M$, where $(N:s):=\{x\in M\mid sx\in N\}$ (this is a generalization of (3.11.ii); the proof is analogous). Suppose then $x\in Q^{ce}$. There is $x\in M$ such that $sx\in Q$. To look for a contradiction, suppose $x\not\in Q$. Then $s$ is a zero-divisor in $M/Q$; thus, $s$ is nilpotent in $M/Q$, i.e., $s\in r_M(Q)=\p$; contradicting the hypothesis that $S$ does not meet $\p$. Therefore $x\in Q$. This proves the implication to the right in part 1. For the converse, we will use the following

Lemma. Let $A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism, $M$ be an $A$-module and $N$ be a $B$-module. Let $M\to N$ be an $A$-linear map. If $P\subset N$ is a primary $B$-submodule of $N$, then $P^c$ is a primary $A$-submodule of $M$.

The lemma follows by leveraging the $A$-linear injection $M/P^c\to N/P$. Suppose then that $S^{-1}Q$ is $S^{-1}\p$-primary. The lemma gives $Q$ is primary; say it is $\q$-primary. We want to see that $\p=\q$. Firstly, since $S^{-1}Q$ is primary, in particular $S^{-1}Q\neq S^{-1}M$, whence $\q\cap S=\varnothing$, by part 1. By the previously proven implication, $S^{-1}Q$ is $S^{-1}\q$-primary; thus $S^{-1}\q=S^{-1}\p$, and therefore $\q=\p$.
Finally, Yu proved that every $S^{-1}A$-submodule of $S^{-1}M$ is an extended submodule (i.e., is of the form $S^{-1}N$, for some $A$-submodule $N\subset M$), hence the one-to-one correspondence is due to Lemma 1.17⁎.  $\square$
Lastly, in Theorem 4.10⁎'s statement, one should say “let $\{\p_{i_1},\dots,\p_{i_m}\}$ be an isolated set of prime ideals of $N$,” where isolated set is defined analogously: a downward-closed subset of the primes ideals belonging to $N\subset M$.
